# How to generate the following control using html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following control with HTML / CSS.  I need advice on the best way to implement this with solely HTML and CSS.  I was able to implement it using different anchor () tags.  But I am not sure that this is the best approach since it all has the same purpose.

The link, blue circle, and cart icon should take you to a different page.

Also - for the icon I am implementing font-awesome.  http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Any advice and suggestions would be appreciated!

Here is a picture:

[image]

Here is my HTML so far - but I dont think it's the best approach...

```
        <div id="check_out_utility" class="float_right">
          <a id="check_out_utility_link" class="white_link float_left" href="#">Check Out</a>
          <div id="shopping_cart" class="float_right">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x white_color"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Again, thanks

Comment: What's your html/css so far?

Comment: You want to whole block to link to a page?

Comment: Yes - the whole block would link to a checkout page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use absolute positioning within the cart icon.

I build a quick example from scratch

**HTML:**

```
<a class="cart" href="#">
    Checkout
    <span class="fa  fa-2x fa-shopping-cart">
        <span class="badge">3</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cart {
    background-color: #2F4178;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;

}

.cart .fa {
    position: relative;
}
.cart .badge {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #478BFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jqac30Lz/